# некорректный вывод количества очков по завершении игры Unity

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-ui

Столкнулся с проблемой конечного вывода очков. Основная проблема что по завершении уровня показывается панель в отображением очков набранных пользователем, в ней не учитываются очки с последнего хода, а так же которые были набраны после (игра по типу 3 в ряд, после последнего хода могут сгенерироваться объекты которые совпадут в одном ряду и уничтожатся. Очки приплюсуются, но в конечном меню эти очки не прибавятся как и с последнего хода).

Проблема наглядно - [тык](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjWQM.jpg)

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
//using System.Threading;

public class UI : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static UI instance;

    public Text textScore, textMoves;
    private int score = 0;
    private int moves = 10;

    public GameObject panelGameOver;
    public Text gTextScore, gTextBestScore;

    private void Awake()
    {
        instance = this;
    }

    public void Score(int value)
    {
        score += value;
        textScore.text = "Score: " + score.ToString();
    }

    public void Moves(int value)
    {
        moves -= value;
        if (moves <= 0)
        {
            GameOver();
        }
        textMoves.text = "Moves: " + moves.ToString();
    }

    private void GameOver()
    {
        if (score > PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Score"))
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Score", score);
            gTextBestScore.text = "New Best: " + score.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            gTextBestScore.text = "New Best: " + PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Score");
        }
//        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        gTextScore.text = "Score: " + score.ToString();
        panelGameOver.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В Вашем случае проверка на GameOver должна происходить не когда ходы закончились а когда понятно что на игровом поле больше ничего не случится и там уже проверять количество оставшихся ходов и вызывать GameOver.

Comment: lol. Он прямо напросился на капитана очевидность .